# Compare two ADO.net Entity Data Models

Tags: ado.net, compare, entity

I have an ADO.net Entity Data Model. That model need to be deployed to multiple sites. But issue is that **For site 1**, I need to deploy **A B C entities** and some **x y z function imports** but **for site 2**, I need to deploy **C D E Entities** and **U V W X function imports.**

So basically I want to deploy different selected portion for **a** UTIX model to different sites? I have one development site and model used in that site need to be deployed over to like 5 different sites with small alterations but I don't want to deploy full data model to all sites.
Basically their are some client specific changes in data model which I don't want that some other client should get.

Maintaining separate development sites for each client increases too much development cost for me and its simply out of question.

So just as we can compare two SQL databases using RedGate SQL Compare or VS Schema compare Tools and can move only selected tables, procedure, functions. Do we have something similar to compare ADO.net Entity Data Model?

Answer (score 0):

You are in control of your entity model. You choose what objects are contained in this development artifact. How you choose to partition "code" is up to you.